# How to reverse a list and combine it with a set in python?

Tags: python

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
ste = {1,2,3,4,5,6}    
test = dict(zip(lst,ste))
print(test)
```

i don't want a result like this :

```
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6}
```

i need a result like this :

```
{6: 1, 5: 2, 4: 3, 3: 4, 2: 5, 1: 6}
```

How can i reverse a list and combine it with a set using zip function ?

Comment: no i want to reverse a list and combine it with another set

Comment: Sets *aren't ordered*.  There is absolutely nothing you can do here that would produce guaranteed, repeatable results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you would need to do is reverse one of the two iterables, and since sets aren't indexable you are stuck with reversing the `list`.  You also need to make sure that the first parameter of the zip function is the descending iterable in order to make sure that the first key in the `dict` is the largest number.

```
test = {i:j for i,j in zip(lst[::-1], ste)}
```

or

```
test = dict(zip(lst[::-1],ste))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
lst = list(reversed(lst))
ste = {1,2,3,4,5,6}    
test = dict(zip(lst,ste))
print(test)
```